# Please reopen sshuttle question 935144

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

My original question posted at [Can I use expose remote server ports via sshuttle?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935144) was a bit confused and made a half-attempt at answering itself. I've made it simpler so that it can be re-opened.

And thanks to my friendly neighborhood sysadmin I have an answer ready to post too :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the edit.